# Android: Open URL with button for downloadable media but without Opening a browser window. How?

Tags: android, uri

Is it possible to open a URL without having the browser open up the link?

I have followed a few tutorials but cannot manage this task

The url i'am opening is a media content url (.dd) so i do not need to have the browser display anything, only access the url to then trigger the download.

Here is the code which opens the url in a browser window then performs the download, but how do i open the URL without opening a browser window, almost like it is opening in the background?

Hope someone can show me how?

Thankyou, Lucy

```
Button openURLLButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save); // Retrieve the button from the XML file
    openURLButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  //Add a listener for when the button is pressed
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openUrl();          
        }
    });
}

protected void openUrl() {
    String url = "http://domain.com/download.dd"; 
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); // Create a new intent - stating you want to 'view something'
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));  // Add the url data (allowing android to realise you want to open the browser)
    startActivity(i); // Go go go!
}
```

}

Comment: What do you want to do with the file?  You could always retrieve the file as an `InputStream` using `HttpURLConnection`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick reply, I'm not realy sure how to in-corperate that, could you show me how i would do that using the code above to open from a button, Thanks, Lucy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected InputStream openUrl() {
    String url = "your url";
    InputStream stream;
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(url).openConnection();
    if (connection.ResponseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        stream = connection.getInputStream();
    }
    return stream;
}
```

The above code (I haven't included the required exception handling) would get the url as an `InputStream`.  It then depends on what you want to do with the data.  The `InputStream` is basically an array of bytes.  I am not familiar with *.dd as a file type but once you have the stream of data you can then use other `InputStream` or `OutputStream` subclasses, to manipulate it, such as `FileOutputStream` to write the data to a file.

Edit:

If you wish to alter wallpapers then look at `WallpaperManager` in the sdk reference.  It allows you to set a wallpaper from a `Drawable` and also an `InputStream`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks but that is far to technical for my novice brain, all i want to do is download an image from a server or from the app via res/drawables and make it available for a user to see in their gallery, so they can simply set as a wallpaper if they wish. I have been trying to do this for weeks now and i cannot find any tutorials or laymans terms to describe how to do it. I do know that after the image is downloaded or saved to SD the MediaScanner needs to refresh to allow the gallery to have the image ready for the user. Could someone please show me how to do this, pretty please.. Lucy

Comment: Lucy, it sounds like you need to buy a book on programming Android or google harder for code you can copy and paste but look at the `WallpaperManager` class in the sdk reference as I mention in my edit.